# CSS Text wrap should treat floated element as a column

Tags: css, css-float

**Here is the resulting layout**, the text is wrapping under the label "Dates".
[image: The problem]

**Here is the desired result:**
[image: The desired result]

Here is the html layout:

```
<div class="alternate">
    <span class="label">Dates:</span>
    <span id="lblDates">
        Created: <u>May 31, 2011</u>, Quote: <u>Sep 1, 2011</u>, Completed: <u>May 23, 2012</u>, Invoice: <u>May 1, 2011</u>, Finalized: <u>May 31, 2011</u>
    </span>
    <br style="clear:both;">
</div>
```

The relevant CSS:

```
    fieldset .label {
        text-align: right;
        float: left;
        width: 150px;
        clear: left;
        margin-right: 15px;
        color: black;
        font-weight: bold;
}
```

If I put a predefined height to the label, then it works, but I don't want a predefined height on the label because sometimes I have only one line of content, how can I achieve this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should help

```
#lblDates {
    padding-left: 165px;
    display: block;
}
```

Here is the [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/fvMFW/4/)

Comment: Any way to do it without hardcoding the width in the other span?

Comment: Under hardcoding, do you mean giving span width or giving span width in pixels? I mean, it is trivial with relative widths, using percentage

Comment: No, I mean that the second span must always be styled in coordination with the first one. If another style would impact the width of the label, then the lblDates padding must also be changed.

Answer (score 0):

put `margin-left: 165px` (165px = 150px + 15px, the width + margin you have set on the label) and `display:block` on `#lblDates`